# Error saving intermediate table

Tags: java, jpa

I have this related entities

**Entity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class Entidad extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * Serial
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3453805453717178734L;

    protected String name;

    protected String image;

    protected String notes;

    @OrderBy("id")
    @ManyToMany
    protected Set<EntityHeader> headersType = new HashSet<EntityHeader>();

    //Getters and setters
}
```

**HeaderType.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "header_type")
public class HeaderType extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * Serial
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7471230510640592406L;

    private String name;

    @OrderBy("id")
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<EntityHeader> entities = new HashSet<EntityHeader>();

    //Getters and setters
}
```

And the intermediate table **EntityHeader.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_header")
public class EntityHeader implements Serializable{

    /**
     * Serial
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1710372870796468955L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Entidad entity;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private HeaderType headerType;

    private String value;

    //Getters and setters

}
```

So, when I want to save a Entity without EntityHeader data it does well, but, if I try to set EntityHeader fields and save it (saving person or saving EntityHeader alone with Entity and HeadersType with right values) I get this message:

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class es.paquete.basicas.entidades.intermedias.EntityHeader. Expected:
>   class es.paquete.basicas.entidades.intermedias.EntityHeader, got class
>   java.lang.Long

**EDIT**: Ids of main classes are in BaseEntity

Comment: Multiple Id fields mean you need to define an IdClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that, in my opinion, have to be fixed to make these entities work:

- each entity must have its own @Id field
- it feels like the @ManyToMany relathionships are out of place; actually, each **Entidad** and each **HeaderType** have a one-to-many relation with their **EntityHeader**

I think your classes should look something like this:

**Entidad.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class Entidad extends BaseEntity {

    /**
    * Serial
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3453805453717178734L;

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE) -- this annotations enables automatic generation for table ids
    protected Long id;

    protected String name;

    protected String image;

    protected String notes;

    @OrderBy("id")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity")
    protected Set<EntityHeader> headersType = new HashSet<EntityHeader>();

    //Getters and setters
}
```

**HeaderType.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "header_type")
public class HeaderType extends AbstractBasicEntity {

    /**
     * Serial
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7471230510640592406L;

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE) -- this annotations enables automatic generation for table ids
    protected Long id;

    private String name;

    @OrderBy("id")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "headerType")
    private Set<EntityHeader> entities = new HashSet<EntityHeader>();

    //Getters and setters
}
```

**EntityHeader.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_header")
public class EntityHeader implements Serializable{

    /**
     * Serial
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1710372870796468955L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Entidad entity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private HeaderType headerType;

    private String value;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

This solution has to be refined, but I hope it helps you to get on the right path.

PS: Sorry if I have made any English mistake.

Comment: Actually, HeaderType and Entidad have an Id, the field is in BaseEntity

Comment: @Kratul I had imagined something like that, but I just wanted to be sure the id was present in each entity involved

Answer (score 3):

Your primary keys on EntityHeader don't make sense :

The @Id annotation

> Specifies the primary key of an entity. The field or property to which
>   the Id annotation is applied should be one of the following types: any
>   Java primitive type; any primitive wrapper type; String; 
>   java.util.Date;  java.sql.Date;  java.math.BigDecimal; 
>   java.math.BigInteger.

Take a look at http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/ManyToOne

You will need to look at the primary keys for your entities so that they can reference each other as well.